# Convert datetime to string in php with DateTime::CreateFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

```
$expdate2 = "06/01/2012";
$time = '6 months';

$expdate2 = date_create($expdate2);
date_add($expdate2, date_interval_create_from_date_string($time));
$expdate = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $expdate2);
$expdate = $expdate->format('m/d/Y');
```

My date add works fine, but I need to get the date back to a string. Basically I am starting with the string, 06/01/2012 and I want to add a varying amount of months too it. Php.net says to use `DateTime::createFromForma`t but I am getting the error,

> PHP Warning:  DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be
>   string, object given in  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function
>   format() on a non-object in

How can parameter 2 be a string when I am trying to convert it back to a string?

Comment: try $future = strtotime('21 July 2012');

Comment: You're adding an extra step. Rather than creating a new DateTime object, just do: $expdate2->format('m/d/Y');